# Similarity measure/metric for long time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I'm looking for a similarity measure/metric to cluster long time-series datasets. I feel that Euclidean distance won't do any good for my application, for it is not robust enough to detect patterns that are shifted in time. My primary intention was to use Dynamic Time Warping, but the algorithm just doesn't converge with my time-series dataset. This could be due to the fact that my time series are extremely long. I am looking for the next suitable alternative.

P.S: I am thankful to the community for replying to my question, in the absence of data. I was essentially looking for a technique that could work well with any generic time-series dataset. I know that there is currently no (and probably will never be) any metric that fits all datasets, but I still wanted to test different metrics on the sets of proprietary data that my project contains and see what works best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is almost meaningless without showing/explaining the data.

The tells you want invarinces you need (phase. offset, amplitude, uniform scaling, warping, complexity etc [a]).
But see for example [b]

[a] https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Complexity-Invariant%20Distance%20Measure.pdf

[b] https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_bitmaps.pdf

Answer (score 1):

DTW does not have a notion of "convergence", as it is not an iterative optimization procedure.

When DTW is too *slow*, and doesn't finish in acceptable time, the obviously next best idea is to use bounded DTW.

Full DTW can take O(nm) time of n and m are the lengths of your series (at least if implemented well...). You can bound this to O(nk) for a fixed maximum shift k. Also, **aggregation may be a good idea**, or extracting features for example with a Fourier transformation.

We can't tell what is right for you because we don't have your data...